# Divide local maven repository

Tags: maven, repository

I need to split user's local repository (usually ***~/.m2***) into two parts. The first part is used only for downloading common modules (artifacts used by many users on the same computer). it has to be publicly readable. The second part is used for copying artifacts from one module to another in the same user account. It is private for a specific user and invisible for all others.

I found different solutions for changing local user repository, for making this local repository common for many users, for using mirrors, but nothing that meets my specification.

Comment: The folder `~/.m2/` is per user by default and is not shared with other user and should never being shared with other users...cause this is by default `$HOME/.m2/` which is the home folder of the user...

Comment: I know that. I need one more shared place to keep the downloaded artifacts.

Comment: Shared place does not make sense...nor is it supported and furthermore I don't the need for such things...

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered running an instance of [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) on the computer? This can be used to cache jars retrieved from upstream repositories like [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/), making builds more efficient.

Once installed you configure Maven to use it for all dependencies.

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  ..
  ..
```

Comment: Yes, but it is not a solution as it won't prevent caching of all of the artifacts in user's local cache ~/.m2. We need two-level cache: one for downloaded and another for locally changed artifacts.

Comment: @GMichael You are fixating on a capability that is not supported by Maven. The ~/.m2 directory is a cache, you can run an instance of Nexus to act as an alternative cache. It's also possible to publish artifacts to Nexus, so it could be used to both cache and store artifacts, this is what Maven repository managers do.